# How to check whether a radio button is selected which is created inside a data grid dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a data grid which is populated at runtime with some values. The first two columns are for radio buttons with 1st column containing 'Yes' and second being 'No' . 
There are `n` number of rows in the data grid. If even one 'Yes' is selected a text box should appear.
How do I achieve this?

I tried it by using

```
$(".class").each(function () {
    if ($(this).checked) {
        textbox.visible = true;
    }
});
```

But `$(this).checked` is returning false

Comment: Use `if(this.checked)`. A jQuery object doesn't have a checked property, the underlying element does

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `prop` which returns true/false based on weather it is checked or not.

```
$(".class").each(function() {
   if( $(this).prop('checked') ) 
   {  
      textbox.visible = true; 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will answer your question

```js
$('.class').click(function(){

$(".class").each(function()
{
  if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val()=='yes' ) {  
      console.log($(this).prop('name') + ' checked'); 
    } 
 }); 
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
<tr>
  <td>Yes</td><td>No</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name='question1' value='yes' type='radio' class='class'/></td><td><input name='question1' type='radio' class='class'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name='question2'  value='yes' type='radio' class='class'/></td><td><input name='question2' type='radio' class='class'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name='question3' value='yes'  type='radio' class='class'/></td><td><input name='question3' type='radio' class='class'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```